# Unable to recognise the Jmeter issue

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I was testing a blog but I didn't get any output not even for just 2 threads. Please help in this. Sharing the image with you:

[image: Screenshot - output issue jmeter]

Comment: Share jmeter log file

Comment: 2016/06/09 13:20:30 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test! 

2016/06/09 13:20:30 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []

Comment: 2016/06/09 13:20:30 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is done: testing for uatblog 1-1 

2016/06/09 13:20:30 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: testing for uatblog 1-1 

2016/06/09 13:20:30 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test 

2016/06/09 13:20:30 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false,*local*)

Comment: Hi @Adnan I have given the first 2 and last 3 lines of the log file

Comment: The test is done but it throws an error. Analyse the output using "View Results Tree" listener.It will provide you with the error code and response

Comment: Hi @Adnan its showing HTTP Request over the text section

Comment: @Adnan can you please help me what kind of error it is ?

Comment: Create an element called "Result Tree", run your test with it and see the exact details about every request.

Answer (score 1):

You have `555` value int `Bytes` column - so some output should be present.

If you run your test in [non-GUI mode (hope you do)](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode) you can configure JMeter to store response body on error.

Add the next 2 lines to *user.properties* file (it's located in JMeter's "bin" folder)

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data.on_error=true
```

JMeter restart will be required to pick the properties up

When your test is over:

1. Open JMeter GUI
2. Add [View Results Tree listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree)
3. Using "Browse" button locate .jtl results file and open it
4. Analyze response message and body.